# Does a synonym for "burro" exist in Spanish, cognate to Sicilian "sceccu"?

Tags: etimología, animales, false-cognate

I am trying to understand the etymology of the Sicilian word "sceccu", which means "burro". Some common explanations for its etymology are that it derives from Turkish [*eşek*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sceccu#Etymology) ("donkey") or Arabic [شيخ‎](http://bloggers.iitaly.org/bloggers/34039/joseph-f-privitera-creative-sicilian-language-teacher-towards-southern-italian-americ) ("sheikh"), but I don't find these satisfactory and suspect it has a different origin.

I found some similar looking words with the same meaning in some western romance languages:

- "jegue" (Portuguese)
- "jeque" (Old Provençal)
- "xeque"

Does a similar word exist in Spanish, and if so, what is its etymology?

I guess that "equus" is involved, but I don't understand the j-x-sh at the beginning.

Comment: [*sceccu*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sceccu) comes from Turkish *eşek*, and [*jeque*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jeque) (cognate with *sheik*) comes from Arabic. [*jegue*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jegue) is however a Portuguese word of uncertain etymology, possibly a loan from English *jackass* (see the similar pt. [*jeque*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/jeque) from English *jack*). Spanish does have *yegua* (mare) derived from Latin *equa* (female of *equus*), but again this is etymologically unrelated. You may want to post this on the Portuguese stack exchange.

Comment: Hi, Fabio. "Jegue" and "xeque" do not seem Spanish words, and "[jeque](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MPfRqaz)" means a completely different thing. Are you asking for the etymology of Italian words? I'm not sure about what your question really is. Are you searching for alternatives in the Spanish language to the word "burro"?

Comment: Thank you guys. I am trying to understand the etymology of "sceccu", which is burro in Sicilian. I am asking if there is an OLD spanish (or maybe català) word used before "burro". This because I found "jeque" in old Provencal and "jegue" in Portuguese with that very same meaning.
The "Sheik" and the "Turkish" explanations are not satisfactory, from my point of view.

Comment: Hi @FabioG.- I made some edits to your question based on your comment. Does this accurately reflect what you wished to ask? Note: *xeque* in Old Spanish (modern *jeque*) does not mean "*burro*" - it only means "Sheikh". Also, can you let us know where you found this info on the Provençal word?

Comment: Hi Ukemi, yes, it does. The Provencal "jeque" is used very often to explain the etymology of sceccu, you find that in many sources: honestly, I don't remember where or when I found that, it's just something I know. That doesn't make it right, of course, but the correspondence with the Portuguese "jegue" made me think about the existence of a similar word in ancient Spanish. The etymology from "Sheikh" is the only alternative I found, but, well, it just doesn't sound right: a popular story says we begun to use "sceccu" to mock the "Sheikh"...

Comment: I don't think that the Sicilian word has any connection to Spanish at all.

Comment: Lambie, we have several words of Spanish origin. Sicily has been an Aragonese-Spanish dominion for centuries, and we have in common the Arab conquest: why do you exclude that option for this specific word?
Plus, I am trying to understand the etymology of an (hypotetical) old Spanish synonim of "burro", which can help.

Comment: Also [according to Rohlfs](http://sites.unice.fr/site/henneboi/SVG-lirces/langues/real/dialectes/scauciare.htm) the origin is Turkish *ešek*, but it may have been  introduced through some Arabic speaking.

Comment: Sicily was a possession of Aragon. Yes. Not has been. I am sure therefore  there are many words of Spanish origin. That doesn't prove anything here for THIS word.

Answer (score 1):

#### Etymology of *sceccu*

As you note, the etymology for this word has several competing hypotheses, some more convincing than others:

| Original | Translation |
| --- | --- |
| In ogni caso l'etimologia di tale termine e dell'italiano « ciuco » (« ciuchino »), viene dalla voce turca « ešek » = asino (che va letta « escièk »), dalla quale chiaramente deriva il sicilianissimo: « sceccu ». - *Voci orientali nei dialetti di Liguria*, Lorenzo Lanteri (1982) | In any case, the etymology of this term and also the one of Italian "ciuco" ("ciuchino"), comes from Turkish "ešek" = donkey (pronounced like "escièk"), from which Sicilian word "sceccu" clearly derives. |

Your suggestion that it is cognate to *equus* (and thus modern Spanish *yegua* and *cebra*<sup>1</sup>) has been proposed before, but the author notes that some etymologists have criticised this as superficially tempting but false:

| Original | Translation |
| --- | --- |
| La fantasia poi l'abbiamo tutti! Se attribuii *sceccu* ad *equus*, per la trafila dell'afr. *jeque*, non ho nè fantasticato, nè supposto miscele eteroclite di voci. Anche l'Avolio avea intravveduto tale etimologia, che pure è stata accettata dal Cesareo. - [*Studi glottologici italiani*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ieaICeGXm3UC&dq=%22sceccu%22), Vol 8 (*sceccu*), [Vol 3 (*equus*)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ieaICeGXm3UC&dq=%22sceccu%22) (1928) | We can all have imagination! *Sceccu* has been attributed to *equus*, through the route from afr. *jeque*, but I have neither fantasised nor supposed heteroclitic mixtures of vocables. Also Avolio had foreseen such etymology, and has been accepted by Cesareo. |

#### Spanish cognates

If derived from Latin *equus*, there are two Spanish cognates with similar meanings I am aware of:

- *yegua* ← equa
- *cebra* ← zebra ← ezebra ← *eciferus ←  equiferus ← equus  + ferus

Comment: Good answer. However, not sure how reopening the question to then answer to the Sicilian part is helpful to the Spanish site

Comment: This source is an [etymological dictionary of dialectal forms](http://sites.unice.fr/site/henneboi/SVG-lirces/langues/real/dialectes/scauciare.htm) created in  the university of Nice. It's mentioned that, according to Gerhard Rohlfs in his *Nuovo Dizionario dialettale della Calabria*, Longo ed., Ravenna, 1977 [: 1990], the origin of Calabro-Sicilian word *sceccu* is Turkish *ešek*, but it may have been introduced through some Arabic speaking.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming': The summary that I get from all this is that the fact that Sicilian *sceccu* was etymologically related to an Spanish word was actually proposed in the past, but more recent studies seem to refute this hypothesis.

Comment: @Charo yes, I understand (although the translation into Spanish of the relevant parts of the quotes would be useful, since we just can assume English and Spanish understanding in this site). However, my point is that the answer is Sicilian-based, while I think the useful part is to focus on the Spanish one. Specially, to the part that makes it on-topic_ish_ to the site _Does a similar word exist in Spanish, and if so, what is its etymology?_. (BTW since the OP is long gone now, it is not a bad idea to have reformatted the question to make it more fittable to the site)